# iterating over pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

i have the following code:

data has column name of col_name.

```
data = pd.csv_read("somedata.csv")
for row in data:
     print(row)
```

This prints just the column name of col_name. Why is it not iterating over the entire column?

Comment: show how your data looks like ! anyway you need to use `for index, row in data.iterrows():`

Comment: why do you want to iterate over a df, that is usually a very bad idea. What are you trying to accomplish on each row?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη That worked!!! Thanks If you can can copy that to answer i will mark it.

Comment: @newcoder you welcome. below is my answer :)

Comment: @ksooklall I don't need to just for academic reasons wanted to know why i was not able to! Still i am not sure why I need iterrows() because i dont need to use that if that was a string!

Comment: @newcoder because you are dealing with csv dict which is holding key and value

Comment: Please pay attention to what @ksooklall wrote. Explicit iteration should be a last resort. `.iterrows()` should only ever be in used in a bargain with the devil in exchange for world peace. Pandas, comes with it’s own idioms and best practices, please familiarize yourself with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
```

Comment: **Do not use `.iterrows()`.** Just don’t. Use `.itertuples()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
for column in data:
    print(data[column])
```

or

```
for key,value in data.iteritems():
     print(key,value)
     print()
```

Comment: `.iteritems()` seems like it also has one of the same disadvantages of `.iterrows()`. I strongly recommend using `.itertuples()` instead.